# intersection point line with 3d parabolic

Tags: geometry

I try to find intersection point between line and Paraboloid surface in 3D. I have 2 point on the line (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) and the Paraboloid equation namely the Q matrix from here: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/simple.html

How can I find the intersection between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find the answer
We calculate the  normal vector from $p_1$ to $p_2$   $(a_p, b_p, c_p)$
and then we can calculate:

$x=x_1+at$

$y=y_1+at$

$z=z_1+at$

and then placed in the data equation. 
We get one equation with one unknown- t .